# Getting error while adding proguard

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, applozic

Logcat:

```
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.JFrame
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe$1: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ActionListener
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.OutlineNode: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPrintPage: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.print.Printable
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPrintPage$1: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.AbstractAction
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.JFrame
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.KeyListener
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$1: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.AbstractAction
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$10: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.AbstractAction
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$11: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.AbstractAction
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$12: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.AbstractAction
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$13: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.WindowAdapter
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$14: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ActionListener
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$16: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$2: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.AbstractAction
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$3: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.AbstractAction
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$4: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.AbstractAction
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$5: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.AbstractAction
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$6: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.AbstractAction
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$7: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.AbstractAction
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$8: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.AbstractAction
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$9: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.AbstractAction
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$ThumbAction: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.AbstractAction
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer$ZoomAction: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.AbstractAction
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PagePanel: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.JPanel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PagePanel: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.image.ImageObserver
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PagePanel: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.MouseListener
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PagePanel: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PdfSubByteSampleModel: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.image.SampleModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.RefImage: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.ThumbPanel: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.JPanel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.ThumbPanel: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.Scrollable
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.ThumbPanel: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.image.ImageObserver
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.ThumbPanel$1: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.MouseAdapter
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.colorspace.CMYKColorSpace: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.color.ColorSpace
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.colorspace.CalGrayColor: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.color.ColorSpace
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.colorspace.CalRGBColor: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.color.ColorSpace
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.colorspace.LabColor: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.color.ColorSpace
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.colorspace.MaskColorSpace: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.color.ColorSpace
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.decode.MyTracker: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.image.ImageObserver
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.pattern.PatternType1$1: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.Paint
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.pattern.PatternType1$Type1PaintContext: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.PaintContext
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.pattern.ShaderType2$Type2Paint: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.Paint
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.pattern.ShaderType2$Type2PaintContext: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.PaintContext
Warning:test.FontToy: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.JPanel
Warning:test.FontToy$1: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ItemListener
Warning:test.FontToy$2: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ItemListener
Warning:test.FontToy$3: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.KeyAdapter
Warning:test.FontToy$4: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.WindowAdapter
Warning:test.FontToy$5: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ActionListener
Warning:test.FontToy$6: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.event.ChangeListener
Warning:test.FontToy$7: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter
Warning:test.TTFTest$1: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.WindowAdapter
Warning:test.TestType1CFont: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.JPanel
Warning:test.TestType1CFont: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.KeyListener
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.Cache: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsDevice
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFrame
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsDevice
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFrame
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFrame
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.Container
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFrame
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsDevice
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced method 'void dispose()' in program class com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsDevice
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.Container
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsDevice
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFrame
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsDevice
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JComponent
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsDevice
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.DisplayMode
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsDevice
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsDevice
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFrame
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced method 'void setUndecorated(boolean)' in program class com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JButton
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class java.awt.Color
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JButton
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class java.awt.Dimension
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JButton
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced method 'java.awt.Container getContentPane()' in program class com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class java.awt.Container
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced method 'void pack()' in program class com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class java.awt.Rectangle
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced method 'void setLocation(int,int)' in program class com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced method 'void setVisible(boolean)' in program class com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFrame
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsDevice
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class java.awt.Color
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class java.awt.Dimension
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class java.awt.Container
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class java.awt.Rectangle
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsDevice
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JButton
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class java.awt.Dimension
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe: can't find referenced class java.awt.Rectangle
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe$1: can't find referenced class java.awt.event.ActionListener
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.FullScreenWindow$PickMe$1: can't find referenced class java.awt.event.ActionEvent
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.ImageInfo: can't find referenced class java.awt.Color
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.ImageInfo: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.ImageInfo: can't find referenced class java.awt.Color
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.ImageInfo: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.ImageInfo: can't find referenced class java.awt.Color
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.ImageInfo: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.ImageInfo: can't find referenced class java.awt.Color
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.ImageInfo: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.ImageInfo: can't find referenced class java.awt.Color
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.OutlineNode: can't find referenced class javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.OutlineNode: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.Object getUserObject()' in program class com.sun.pdfview.OutlineNode
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.OutlineNode: can't find referenced method 'void setUserObject(java.lang.Object)' in program class com.sun.pdfview.OutlineNode
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.OutlineNode: can't find referenced class javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFChangeStrokeCmd: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFCmd: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile: can't find referenced method 'void add(javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode)' in program class com.sun.pdfview.OutlineNode
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile: can't find referenced method 'javax.swing.tree.TreeNode getParent()' in program class com.sun.pdfview.OutlineNode
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFFillAlphaCmd: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFFillPaintCmd: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferByte
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.PackedColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.color.ColorSpace
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Color
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageReader
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageReader
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageReadParam
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageReadParam
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageReader
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.RasterFormatException
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.IndexColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.IndexColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.color.ColorSpace
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.color.ColorSpace
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Color
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageReadParam
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.SampleModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageReader
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.RasterFormatException
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.IndexColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBuffer
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.SampleModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.color.ColorSpace
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$DecodeComponentColorModel: can't find referenced method 'int getAlpha(java.lang.Object)' in program class com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$DecodeComponentColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$DecodeComponentColorModel: can't find referenced class java.awt.color.ColorSpace
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced field 'int pixel_bits' in program class com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced method 'int getNumComponents()' in program class com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.PixelInterleavedSampleModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced method 'int getTransferType()' in program class com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.PixelInterleavedSampleModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced method 'int getPixelSize()' in program class com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.MultiPixelPackedSampleModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.SampleModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.SampleModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced class java.awt.color.ColorSpace
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.SampleModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.SampleModel
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage$PdfComponentColorModel: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFImageCmd: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Dimension
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Color
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.AffineTransform
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.AffineTransform
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Color
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Dimension
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ImageObserver
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ImageObserver
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ImageObserver
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ImageObserver
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.AffineTransform
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.AffineTransform
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.AffineTransform
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.GeneralPath
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPaint: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPaint: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.GeneralPath
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPaint: can't find referenced class java.awt.Shape
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPaint: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPaint: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.GeneralPath
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPaint: can't find referenced class java.awt.Shape
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPaint: can't find referenced class java.awt.Paint
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPaint: can't find referenced class java.awt.Color
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPaint: can't find referenced class java.awt.Paint
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPaint: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPaint: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.GeneralPath
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPaint: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPaint: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics2D
Warning:com.sun.pdfview.PDFPaint: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.GeneralPath
```

**Proguard:**

```
    #keep json classes                
 -keepclassmembernames class * extends com.applozic.mobicommons.json.JsonMarker {
    !static !transient <fields>;
 }

 -keepclassmembernames class * extends com.applozic.mobicommons.json.JsonParcelableMarker {
    !static !transient <fields>;
 }
 #GSON Config          
-keepattributes Signature          
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }           
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }            
-keep class org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.logging.JSR47Logger { *; } 
-keep class android.support.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.** { *; }

-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe.**
-dontwarn com.google.gson.examples.android.model.**
-dontwarn org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.logging.JSR47Logger.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn android.support.**

-keep class com.sun.pdfview.**{ *; } 
-dontwarn com.sun.pdfview.** 

-keep class test.**{ *; }
-dontwarn test.**
```

Build:

```
release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

I have enabled the proguard file in debug mode just for testing. I am able to figure out what went wrong.

Using Applozic chat gradle dependency as well.

Edit:- updated Proguard file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line in your proguard file.

1. -dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe{*;}
2. -dontwarn com.google.gson.examples.android.model.**
3. -dontwarn org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.logging.JSR47Logger.**
4. -dontwarn android.support.**
5. -dontwarn android.support.**

Comment: -keep class com.sun.pdfview.{*;}
-dontwarn com.sun.pdfview.**
Same thing you have to do for the remaining warning packages

Comment: I have added the line -keep class com.sun.pdfview.**{ *; }  -dontwarn com.sun.pdfview.** -keep class test.**{ *; } -dontwarn test.** and then build but from past 10 min it is building. Something went wrong?

Comment: Add all the keep and don't lines in your proguard-rules.pro file in your project.Sync and rebuid your project.

Comment: add all the keep and don't lines , I didn't get you. Can you more specifically tell me.

Comment: In your project there will be proguard-rules.pro file add all 
 dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe{*;}
-dontwarn com.google.gson.examples.android.model.**
-dontwarn org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.logging.JSR47Logger.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn android.support.**

-keepattributes Signature          
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }           
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }            
-keep class org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.logging.JSR47Logger { *; } 
-keep class android.support.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.** { *; }
in that file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129494/discussion-between-sagar-gangawane-and-ankur-khandelwal).

Comment: I have left the message in the chat.

Comment: It would be great if you can answer one more query of mine. I have written in chat.